# Has anyone ported globe (the chrome experiment) to the latest threejs version?

Tags: three.js

*Short story:*
The globe code is based (and contains) **threejs v40** while the latest version in github is **threejs r55** at the moment. I was wondering if anybody (more knowledgeable then me in this area) has ported *globe* to a newer threejs version?

*Long story:*
I was fiddling around with googles globe from http://www.chromeexperiments.com/globe.
I noticed that it is based on an old threejs (on github) version. Using the latest version (and getting the same results!) did not prove to be easy. Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12750344/three-js-select-geometry-by-id).

I changed around some function names and fumbled some parameters, no big deal. Then I turned to the shaders. That proved to be more challenging. The old version of threejs seems to have a bug when you do **Mesh.flipSided = true;**: the normal vectors seem to be different in the shaders between old and new version. But the shader code in *globe* was written towards this bug, so I had to correct the shader code.

I now have something that sort of looks the same, but combining the atmosphere and the earth is not working at all. I am suspecting [this threejs bug](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1461) to play a part in it, but I am not sure. Again this is a *flipSided* bug that might have been used by the *globe* authors.

Well, ehm, I am sort of stuck here. I can do what I wanted to do sticking with the old version, but that somehow feels bad.

Can anyone shed some light here?

Comment: Have you checked out the [Migration Wiki](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration) for help upgrading to the current version?

Comment: Yes I had a look there. Unfortunately it misses anything before r45 (for example the rename of `addObject`->`add`). Nothing about shaders in there. I also do not really expect to see a description in there how to fix a misused bug in some version to a valid equivalent (if at all possible) in a later version ;-). Thanks for the pointer anyway.

Answer (score 2):

According to the changelog at https://code.google.com/p/webgl-globe/source/browse/globe/globe.js :

"Nov 5, 2012. Updated to threejs r52 and tweenjs r7."

So, on the surface it sounds like it has been updated... which parts of the code specifically are giving you trouble?

Nowadays, instead of `Mesh.flipSided = true`, in the material of the mesh, you need to set `side:THREE.BackSide` instead.

Can you post or send a link to your code for further investigation?  An updated version of the  globe project sounds like a most worthy endeavor.

Comment: Thank you for the hint! I now realize that I was counting on the download to contain the latest version, which it was not. Not too smart. I now checked out the code in the hg repos and there it seems to work with a later version of threejs. This project has floated out of my immediate attention area so I just did a quick check. I will refresh my memory and try again what I wanted to do back then and maybe run it with the **now-latest** threejs. I will try to remember to report back here ;).